# How to convert timeIntervalSinceNow in swift to a readable date

Tags: ios, swift, nstimeinterval, nstimezone

Hi I am trying to find the time interval between a certain date to the current local time.

```
var a = eventDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
println(a)
//1404567.32182503 - output
```

When I try to do that I am getting the output as mentioned above. How can I change that in to a readable date?

I want to calculate the no.of Day, Hours, Minutes left. i dont want Years, months, Seconds.

MUST: I want the time interval between the eventdate and local time. Not the UTC time.

Here is the full code:

```
//eventDate is 2015-09-01 19:39 
var date = NSDate();
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()
    var localDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
var localDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(localDateString)!

var components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitSecond |
        .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitDay |
        .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: localDate,
        toDate:  self.eventDate, options: nil)

println("\(components.day) days \(components.hour) hours \(components.minute) minutes")

16 days 5 hours 41 minutes //Origianl output
16 days 0 hours 11 minutes // Expected output
```

I think am facing this issue due to change in UTC time!

Comment: Hint: Use  NSCalendar and NSDateComponents. There should be some examples on SO and the Internet.

Comment: Tried. But getting incorrect value because, if I give local time, it takes the UTC time, no matter what!

Comment: Show what you tried, together with your input data, the actual result and the expected result.

Comment: @MartinR please look at the edited question

Comment: The `dateFormat` string is incorrect. Please show example of the original date string. At the very least, I'd use `yyyy` rather than `YYY`.

Comment: Your example is not self-contained, `self.eventDate` is undefined. And why do you convert the `date` to a string and back, using the same formatter?

Comment: [ //eventDate is 2015-09-01 19:39 ] am getting it from Parse

Comment: That time zone is local time. GMT +0530

Comment: @MartinR No, it still give the time difference between eventDate and UTC time. I want the time difference between eventDate and my local time

Comment: @AAA: Please add the output of  `println(date)` and `println(self.eventDate)` to your question.

Comment: It will give the UTC date and eventDate. How can I get the localDate as NSDate?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you want a string representation of the time difference (to display in UI, for example), use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. For example, in Swift 3:

   ```
   let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
   formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute]
   formatter.unitsStyle = .full
   let string = formatter.string(from: date1, to: date2)
   ```

   or, in Swift 2:

   ```
   let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
   formatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .Hour, .Minute]
   formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
   let string = formatter.stringFromDate(date1, toDate: date2)
   ```

   With your example, that will show:

   > 16 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes

   For details on the various properties that configure the behavior of the formatter see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html).
2. In your question, you show us your output:

   > 16 days 5 hours 41 minutes // Original output 
   >   16 days 0 hours 11 minutes // Expected output

   You seem to be inferring from this output that there's some problem in comparing two dates. Your technique for comparing these two dates is fine (though `NSDateComponentsFormatter` simplifies that process, and also generates a localized string, too). But the routine for calculating the elapsed time between two dates is not the issue.

   The problem is that one of your dates (most likely the one you converted with the formatter) is just wrong.
3. In comments, you keep asking different permutations of the same question, "how do I compare dates in my local timezone?", to which the answer is "you don't". Dates don't have time zones. Date strings do, but `NSDate` objects don't.

   If you perform a `print` of `Date`/`NSDate` objects, it will generally show them in GMT (you'll generally see `+0000` after the date, confirming this fact). If you want to see them in your local time zone, use a `DateFormatter` and use `string(from:)` (or in Swift 2, `NSDateFormatter` and use `stringFromDate()`).

   But there's little point in using this `stringFromDate` mechanism (other purely for diagnostic purposes) to see these dates in your local timezone. There's no such thing as "difference between two `NSDate` objects in my local timezone". The `NSDate` objects indicate a single point in time around the world, and the `NSTimeZone` is only necessary if you want to see that point of time shown as a string representation for your local timezone.

Bottom line, the problem is not in the calculation of the elapsed time between two `NSDate` objects, but rather how you created those `NSDate` objects themselves. More than likely, the original string from parse (which you seem reluctant to share with us for some reason) is not in the time zone you think it is.

The most common mistake that people make is assuming the string is in their local time zone, whereas it invariably is in GMT/UTC/Zulu unless the date string explicitly specifies otherwise (e.g. `+0530`). (It's a horrible design to have a web service report dates in local timezone without timezone qualifier, so hopefully you're not doing that.)

Comment: But this also does not consider DST transitions (because the information is lost in `timeIntervalSinceNow`). It would be better do compute the NSDateComponents between the dates first.

Comment: yes, it is showing correct, but with respect to my local time, it should display: 16 days, 5 hours 39 minutes! since my time is GMT+05:30

Comment: @MartinR I disagree. If you're looking for the time elapsed between `eventDate` and now, `timeIntervalSinceNow` does reflect daylight savings. If the results are wrong, the problem rests in the original date string or the formatter used to convert that to a `NSDate`. Unfortunately, without seeing detailed example with the original string, it's hard to diagnose further.

Comment: If i use stringFromDate(localDate) i am getting the correct local date and time as string. How can I change this again to date? If I use dateFromString, it is again being changed to GMT time !!!

Comment: No offense, but this whole discussion suggest some fundamental misconception about `NSDate` objects. Date objects _do not have a timezone._ A timezone is is used when converting strings to dates and back, but `NSDate` objects, themselves, don't have a timezone. It's impossible for us to diagnose where the problem without seeing the original string.

Comment: @Rob: I correct my comment. It seems that NSDateComponentsFormatter assumes the *current date* as a starting point, so it would work correctly in *this* case. Generally, if you want to display the days/hours/minutes between two arbitrary dates, it would be better to compute the difference as NSDateComponents and not as a NSTimeInterval.

Comment: ... as an example the NSTimeInterval from 2015-10-24 00:00 to 2015-10-25 00:00 in the German timezone is 90000.0 seconds = 25 hours, and NSDateComponentsFormatter would display that as 1 day + 1 hour.

Comment: @Rob: Now I disagree :) NSDateComponentsFormatter has two methods stringFromDateComponents and stringFromTimeInterval. The *latter* takes a time interval and has no knowledge *when* that time interval took place and can therefore not know if 90000 seconds are exactly one day (as in the example of my previous comment) or 1 day plus 1 hour. – Btw, the NSDateComponentsFormatter header has a comment *"Normally, NSDateComponentsFormatter will calculate as though counting from the current date and time ..."*

Comment: @MartinR OK, yes, I now see your point. Yes, I agree that you shouldn't use `NSTimeInterval`. But you shouldn't bother with `NSDateComponents` either (unless you really need the individual components). I think `stringFromDate:toDate:` is easiest.